# How to extract a string between brackets in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract a value between the brackets from a string. How can I do that.

For eg: I have this string : Gupta, Abha (01792)

And I want to get the result between the brackets i.e : 01792

I am trying to write a query like this :

```
select substr('Gupta, Abha (01792)',instr('Gupta, Abha (01792)','(')+1,5) from dual;
```

which actually gives me the result. But the problem is that the number of characters between the brackets is not necessariliy always 5.

So I want to avoid hardcoding '5' in the query.

Can somebody please let me know how can I make this query more generic.

Thanks,
Abha

Comment: use regex to pull the characters between the ()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Gupta, Abha (01792)', '\((.+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Oh yes, this works great ! Didnt know about this function...Thanks