# How to extract a string with several lines between brackets in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to extract a value between the brackets from a string.

Here([How to extract a string between brackets in oracle sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904333/how-to-extract-a-string-between-brackets-in-oracle-sql-query)), it is explains how to do.

But in my situation, the string has 2 lines. With this way, I get only NULL.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Gupta, Abha (01792)', '\((.+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM dual --01792

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Gupta, Abha (01
                 792)', '\((.+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM dual -- NULL
```

I known that i can remove the break line symbol and then use regex_substr but i need to keep the break line symbol

Comment: What you need is another option, 'n' or 'm', it depends on your data which one to use.
Check Table 3-2 on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: @Daeron you should convert your comment into an answer.  Working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab452b/23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would adress this with the following regex:

```
\(([^)]*)\
```

This makes use of a custom character class, `[^)]`, which means: everything *but* a closing parenthese. This way, you do not have to worry about line breaks (since, obviously, a line break is not a closing parenthese), or any other special character:

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ff2d9ab989adeee069218433778d7d9)**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Gupta, Abha (01
                 792)', '\(([^)]*)\)') res FROM dual
```

```
| RES                  |
| :------------------- |
| (01                  |
|                 792) |
```