# How to filter and retrieve the results after a Specific characters from stored procedure in oracle plsql?

Tags: oracle, search, filtering, special-characters

I have a column "Names" in the "Employee" table that has following values. The values either contain only single name (first, last, username) or Multiple names separated with semicolon (;). I need to search the values from that table either by first name or last name or username.

I have created a procedure but it is fetching only 1st,4th,5th records. Please let me know how to retrieve 2nd and 3rd records as well.

Firstname and lastname can be given by user with minimum of 2 characters length.
Username is given entire.

**Employee**:

```
ID     Name                                                               Title

1      Andrea Warbutton (awr01)                                        Manager
2      Claire Taylor (cta02);Mark Kites (mak03);Anitha Rooney (anr06)  HOD;Supervisor;Business
3      Dave Rites (dar12);Jessica Simpson (jesi10)                     Lead;Analyst                      
4      Nick Ken (nik56)                                                Product (Local,Regional)
5      Claire Pilkington (cpt09)                                       Sales Owner
```

**Code**:

```
Create or replace empl (pm_firstname varchar2(100), 
                        pm_lastname varchar2(100),
                        pm_username varchar2(100))

BEGIN

Select * from Employee
where Upper(Name) like Upper(pm_firstname ||'%'||) -- this will fetch 1st,4th,5th record
OR Upper(SUBSTR(Name, INSTR(Name),' '+1)) like Upper(pm_lastname ||'%'||) -- this will fetch 1st,4th,5th  record
OR upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name,'\((.+)\)',1,1,NULL,1)) = Upper(pm_username); -- -- this will fetch 1st,4th,5th record

END;

End empl ;
```

Please let me know how to retrieve 2nd and 3rd records as well.

**Desired Output:**

When searched with firstname = "Andrea", the output is below

```
ID     Name                                  Title
1      Andrea Warbutton (awr01)              Manager
```

When searched with firstname = "Claire", the output is below

```
ID      Name                                Title
2      Claire Taylor (cta02)                HOD
5      Claire Pilkington (cpt09)            Sales Owner
```

When searched with lastname = "Simps", the output is below

```
ID     Name                                 Title
3      Jessica Simpson (jesi10)             Analyst
```

When searched with username = "mak03", the output is below

```
ID     Name                                Title
2      Mark Kites (mak03)                 Supervisor
```

When searched with username = "nik56", the output is below

```
ID     Name                                Title
4      Nick Ken (nik56)                   Product (Local,Regional)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with 
  x as (select id, name, '"'||replace(name, ';', '","')||'"' xml from employee),
  n as (select id, name, column_value as cv from x, xmltable(xml))
select id, 
       trim(regexp_substr(cv, '(\S*)(\s)')) fname,
       trim(regexp_substr(cv, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)) lname,
       regexp_substr(cv, '\((.+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) uname
  from n
```

Your task would be much easier if you normalize these data. Above query outputs:

```
ID FNAME    LNAME       UNAME
1  Andrea   Warbutton   awr01
2  Claire   Taylor      cta02
2  Mark     Kites       mak03
2  Anitha   Rooney      anr06
3  Dave     Rites       dar12
3  Jessica  Simpson     jesi10
4  Nick     Ken         nik56
5  Claire   Pilkington  cpt09
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85f7b9c841e9f963d129a66e0fbe2399)</sup>**

Now you can search first, last, usernames however you want. First expression finds first word, then second and [word between brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904333/how-to-extract-a-string-between-brackets-in-oracle-sql-query).

---

**Edit:**

> I posted the table structure with just ID and Name columns. However, I
> have Titles column also in the same format separated with (semicolon).
> In this case, How can I Normalize Titles as well along with Names

This query worked for provided examples:

```
with 
  x as (select id, name, '"'||replace(name, ';', '","')||'"' xmln,
               '"'||replace(title, ';', '","')||'"' xmlt 
          from employee),
  n1 as (select id, trim(xn.column_value) nm, rownum rn from x, xmltable(xmln) xn),
  n2 as (select id, trim(xt.column_value) tt, rownum rn from x, xmltable(xmlt) xt)
select id, trim(regexp_substr(nm, '(\S*)(\s)')) fname,
       trim(regexp_substr(nm, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)) lname,
       regexp_substr(nm, '\((.+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) uname,
       tt title
  from n1 join n2 using (id, rn)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b30c164fea5a5ddf593a0add79318b70)</sup>**

Be careful however, because we cannot write ideal query. If you have entries like Benicio Del Toro, Mary Jo Catlett, Jean Claude Van Damme, it's impossible to write correct regexp. Sometimes second word is part of lastname, sometimes it is firstname, middlename etc.
The proper way is to modify table structure, divide rows, check results and put correct values in correct name columns. Now you have lists which are hard to search and every method may return wrong results.

Comment: Thanks Ponder for your answer. However, I found one issue here. Initially, i posted the table structure with just ID and Name columns. However, I have Titles column also in the same format separated with (semicolon). In this case,  How can I Normalize Titles as well along with Names? Can you please let me know?

Comment: PS:  I have posted the new table structure and Desired Output with the Titles column added.

Answer (score 1):

No need for PL/SQL.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id,
  3      regexp_substr(name, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) name
  4     from employee cross join
  5       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  6                           connect by level <= regexp_count(name, ';') + 1
  7                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  8    )
  9  select id, name
 10  from temp
 11  where instr(name, '&search_for_name') > 0;
Enter value for search_for_name: Claire

        ID NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         2 Claire Taylor (cta02)
         5 Claire Pilkington (cpt09)

SQL> /
Enter value for search_for_name: mak03

        ID NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         2 Mark Kites (mak03)

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `temp` CTE splits semi-colon separated values into rows
- final query uses a simple `instr` function which detects whether "rows" (extracted previously) contain value you're looking for

---

If it must be a function, that code can be reused. As you didn't say what exactly (which datatype, I mean) you want to return, I returned a string.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_search (par_what in varchar2)
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3  is
  4    retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    with temp as
  7    (select id,
  8      regexp_substr(name, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) name
  9     from employee cross join
 10       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                           connect by level <= regexp_count(name, ';') + 1
 12                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13    )
 14    select id ||' - '|| name
 15    bulk collect into retval
 16    from temp
 17    where instr(name, par_what) > 0;
 18
 19    return retval;
 20  end;
 21  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table(f_search('Andrea'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 - Andrea Warbutton (awr01)

SQL> select * from table(f_search('Claire'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 - Claire Taylor (cta02)
5 - Claire Pilkington (cpt09)

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the function code. I tried to create my own function taking into consideration of above code. However, am encountering an error as  "multiset" is not allowed.

Comment: Please, is it possible to add few more filters for the same procedure I posted in the question to get those 2nd and 3rd records?